# Django backwards foreign key manager

Tags: python, django, getattr

I am trying to dynamically get a model's backwards foreign key manager.

If I have:

```
class modelA(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class modelB(models.Model)
    fk = models.ManyToManyField(modelA)
```

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) I can see that I can get the backwards foreign key manager by doing:

```
a = modelB.modela_set
```

in the shell this gives me

```
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager
```

with which I can do

```
a.all()
```

and get a result.

However If I have the string 'modela' and I do:

```
a = getattr(modelB, 'modela_set')
```

I will get

```
django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyToManyDescriptor
```

and if i do:

```
a.all()
```

I get an attribute error.

I do not understand why getattr() is behaving this way.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It was a class vs instance issue.

```
getattr(modelB, 'modela_set')
```

is different than:

```
a = ModelB.objects.get(pk=1)
getattr(a, 'modela_set')
```